# Magento getStoreConfig : get label

Tags: magento, magento-1.8

first of all i have a model class like this :

```
class namespace_mymodule_Model_myclass
    {
        public function toOptionArray()
        {
              return array(
                           array('value'=>'My value',
                                 'label'=>Mage::helper('mymodule')->__('My label name')
                                )
                          );         
        }
    }
```

So i get the value from my configuration like this :

```
Mage::getStoreConfig('section/group/dropdown'); = 'My value'
```

how can i get the label ?

```
????????????????????; = 'My label name'
```

Comment: change class name Namespace_Mymodule_Model_Myclass

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
    class Namespace_Mymodule_Model_Myclass
    {
        public function toOptionArray()
        {
            return array(
                array(
                    'value' => '1',
                    'label' => Mage::helper('mymodule')->__('Label 1')
                ),
                array(
                    'value' => '2',
                    'label' => Mage::helper('mymodule')->__('Label 2')
                ),
                array(
                    'value' => '3',
                    'label' => Mage::helper('mymodule')->__('Label 3')
                )
            );
        }
      public function searchArray($myarray, $value) {
          foreach ($myarray as $item) {
            if ($item['value'] == $value)
               return $item['label'];
          }
         return false;
      }

    }
```

get label from below code

```
$array = Mage::getModel('mymodule/myclass')->toOptionArray();
$value = 2;//search value
$label = Mage::getModel('mymodule/myclass')->searchArray($array ,$value);
echo $label;
```